# add text in google chrome extension icon

Tags: api, google-chrome

I want to add a text showing the minutes spent by the user in the running activity in my Google Chrome extension that called pharaohs Time tracker
can see it here https://chrome.google.com/extensions/developer/edit/cegaadncabdacaplfeondbaodibgjfhi?hl=en

I can't find anything in there API although a lot of people using it like ext called go to IMDB

Answer (score 13):

You can overlay a badge on your browser action by calling [`chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeText) (see also [`chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeBackgroundColor) to style the badge).